# SPI register read returns 0x00 or 0xff

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

I am trying to interface a Arduino Uno with an ASM330LHH using SPI. Whenever I try to read any register, I either get 0xff or 0x00 on the serial monitor

The code I am using:

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define LOOP_DELAY 1000 //ms
uint8_t data;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  /* Refer datasheet for ASM330LHH
   * SPI freq max 10MHz
   * MSB first
   * SPI mode 3
   */
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  

  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  Serial.println("Setup complete!");

}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  byte masked_addr = 0x0F | 0x80;
  Serial.println(masked_addr, BIN);
  
  SPI.transfer(masked_addr);
  data = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  Serial.println(data, BIN);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  delay(LOOP_DELAY);
}
```

The output I get:

```
10001111
11111111
10001111
11111111
10001111
0
10001111
0
```

The expected output for the above code is 0x6B. What might have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: add `SPI.begin();`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it will matter in what you have currently, but SPI.begin() should happen before .beginTransaction()

Comment: `begin` must be called before `beginTransfer` and 10 MHz is to fast for an 16 MHz arduino. 1 MHz should be OK. It might be, that the library correct the 10 Mhz property to a suitable value.

Comment: Just as an aside, your data rate was probably fine.  The Arduino UNO's ATMega328P running 16 MHz, can't run the SPI clock faster than 8 MHz or slower than 125 kHz.  The rate will be clamped to this range, which most SPI devices will handle.  The slower rate is probably better while you're troubleshooting though.

Comment: Your ASM330LHH is a 3.3V device.  You should probably update the question to have a picture/diagram/schematic of however you're interfacing your 5.0V Arduino UNO to it.

Comment: I just connected the Arduino Uno to ADXL345 (Equivalent to ASM330LLH) to test the code. The code works fine. Maybe the ASM330LLH has gone bad. I need to check.

Comment: There is so much I can't see to have any confidence in that idea.  Just to drive the point home: You can't, in the general case, connect a 5V and a 3.3V device together and expect them to work or work *reliably* without /some/, however minor, consideration for the differences.  I'm just guessing you have breakout boards, and those boards may or may not being doing something helpful in interfacing the chip to the Arduino.  Beyond rearranging the pins I mean.